# How to check if the cursor is inside an org-mode "src" block?

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to know if a `point` is inside an org-mode `src` block, so I can disable spell checking.

Is there a fast way to programmatically check this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: As @jagrg points out in a comment, there is a function for that: `org-in-src-block-p` whose doc string says:

> (org-in-src-block-p &optional INSIDE)
>
> Whether point is in a code source block.
> When INSIDE is non-nil, don’t consider we are within a source
> block when point is at #+BEGIN_SRC or #+END_SRC.

Use this method instead of the following answer (which I hope is still useful, so I'll leave it around unless there are objections).

Note that if point is on an empty line after a source block, `org-in-src-block-p` still returns t. That is not important for the OP's use (turning off spell checking in `src` block), but it may be important in other cases. If it *is* important, you'll have to do some extra checking, e.g. by using `org-src--on-datum-p`:

```
(and (org-src--on-datum-p (org-element-at-point)) (org-in-src-block-p))
```

---

[Original answer follows: basically (unnecessarily) implements `org-in-src-block-p` as described above using lower-level primitives, although the real `org-in-src-block-p` is slightly more complicated than what I describe below.]

Use `org-element-at-point` to parse the local region around point and then make a decision based on what it returns. If I eval `(org-element-at-point)` in a src block, I get a result like this:

```el
(src-block (:language "emacs-lisp" :switches nil :parameters nil :begin 135 :end 197 :number-lines nil :preserve-indent nil :retain-labels t :use-labels t :label-fmt nil :value "    (setq foo 'bar)
" :post-blank 3 :post-affiliated 135 :parent nil))
```

So all you need to do is check that the first element is `src-block`:

```el
(defun org-at-src-block-p ()
    (eq (nth 0 (org-element-at-point)) 'src-block))
```

Note that if `point` is on empty lines after a src block, it will still return `t`, but when it is on a line with something else on it, it will return `nil`.

And of course, you can use the same method to identify other places that you are at, by replacing `src-block` with something else: `example-block`, `verse-block` etc. You can even try `table` or `table-row` to check whether you are in a table, but in that case, you should use the built-in function `org-at-table-p`: the empty line problem mentioned above would need more attention in this case.

Comment: Org ships with `org-in-src-block-p`.

Comment: Crud: I searched for `org-at` and did not look any further. Thanks!